# 64K limit not making sense in Android

Tags: android

this is not a technical question.

I'm asking this because I don't understand how can this (64k limit) be avoided.

Aren't a "fancy" app always over 64k methods when it keeps adding functions and features from time to time? Or is that means those 'fancy' apps are always `multidex`-ed?

Comment: *Or is that means those 'fancy' apps are always multidex-ed?* yes.

Comment: It's just the way they designed Dalvik Executable. Quoting [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex): _The Dalvik Executable **specification** limits the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536—including Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own code_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64K indeed doesn't make any sense in the modern era with apps coming with large amount of features, advanced and complex architectures, large libraries(try the full suite of Google Play Services), and the said libraries doing code generation for us like what an DI library like Dagger can do, the Dalvik executable has the 64K limit because thats what its designed for **the limit is on the number of methods that can be referenced not defined**, so we opt for multidexing, by default I would say all debug flavours of an app should have multidexing because without proguard truncating and compressing and removing everything unnecessary out we will eventually hit the 64K limit, but quite often when generating the release variant we would and can quite possibly stay under the 64K limit.

So for your question any app that crosses the 64K limit even after proguard has to be multidexed regardless of whether its fancy or not.